# Not sure how to fix the bug for my card shuffling and dealing python program IndexError: list index out of range cant figgur out

Tags: python

There is a bug near the end, IndexError: list index out of range not sure how to fix it. Any help would be super appreciated. im a new programmer, so solutions is probably easy. english not first language, sorry for bad grammer.

```
import random
#list`enter code here` holders
rank = []
suits = ["hearts", "diamonds", "clubs", "spades"]
royals = ["K", "Q", "J", "A"]
deck = []
players = int(input("Enter the number of players you have - "))
print("")
cardperplayer = 52 / players
cardperplayer = int(cardperplayer)

for a in range(4):
    rank.append(royals[a])


for b in range(2,11):
    rank.append(str(b))

for c in range(4):
    for d in range(13):
    #Decides the face of the card
        card = (rank[d] + " of " + suits[c])
        deck.append(card)

#shuffles deck      
random.shuffle(deck)
while players > 0:
    for e in range(0, cardperplayer):
        print(deck[e])

    print("Those are the cards for player " + str(players))
    print(" ")
    deck.remove(deck[e])
    players -= 1
```

Comment: your code works fine without any error? where is the error happening to you

Comment: I just tried your code on my laptop and it works fine as long as the number of players is less than 52.

Comment: The best way to fix a list index out of bounds error is to not use indices at all. Since lists are directly iterable in Python, more often than not when you process a list you can do so without indices. Also `cardperplayer = 52 / players` should be `cardperplayer = 52 //players` with the next line converting the result to an `int` dropped. `//` is integer division, which makes the `int( ... / ....)` approach not needed.

Comment: You're using `deck[e]` outside of the `for e` loop. That's probably not right.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, and I have a feeling this is an indentation error with your while loop, and an off by one error.

The code as I run it, when I assign 4 players, gives them the same cards. Except for the final card.  Which you are removing from the deck.  Other wise if you remove items from a list during iteration(the loop), you are changing the length of it each loop which is bound to throw an error.

May I suggest creating a count, and after each player gets their cards, assign the count as the starting point for the next players cards to be dealt instead of removing items from your list?

Try this instead of the while loop you've created at the end of the file.
There's no need to destruct the deck.  The print() will help you see what is happening in the code, but feel free to remove them.

````
if players > 0:
    #  the double division below rounds the number to the nearest whole integer
    # odd number of players might create issues with your loops if the deck has remainders. 
    hand = len(deck) // players
    print(hand)
    print(len(deck))

    index = 0
    for split in range(0, players):
        # set count back to zero, this is not a placeholder for where we are in the deck
        count = 0
        # index does not get reset to zero, this is our place in the deck.
        print("--------------hand-----------------")
        while count < hand:  # remember if 0 zero is a start point, we can easily get an off by one error
            print(deck[index])
            print("count = ", count)
            # increment the count so that we only deal out the number of cards needed per player
            count += 1
            # increment index so that we don't have to alter the deck, just move through it without altering it.
            index += 1

       ```
````